# SASS with Ember CLI addons

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli

I'd like to know how I can use SASS within an Ember-CLI addon?

I have my styles in `/app/styles` folder, but I'm not sure that's the right location to have them. I have `broccoli-sass` installed in my addon project, my Dummy test website compiles properly the scss files when I include my folder in `/tests/dummy/app/styles/app.scss`.

`@import 'app/styles/app.scss';`

But I don't know how I can compile the scss files to go into the `/dist/assets/vendors.css`, which is the file loaded by projects using this addon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I just found out the solution

The style folder needs to be in `/addon/styles` instead of `/app/styles`, and the root file should be called addon.scss

Comment: Did you have to still do an import in the dummy app?

Comment: Yes I'm importing it in the dummy app, using `@import 'addon/styles/addon.scss';`

Comment: Were you able to have your addon styles included in a consuming app (i.e. an actual app, not the dummy app)?

Comment: Yes using the above code. Put your styles in `/addon/styles` and you will get them in your actual app.

Comment: @alexmngn and how can others apps import styles of our addon if they just use css and not scss?