# How to use scss in ember addon

Tags: css, ember.js

I am making an emberjs addon and have decided to use scss for styling.

I want to know how can I facilitate my scss styles to the app using my addon if it is not using scss but is just relying in pure css

**More detail:**
I have tested style in dummy app inside addon, I was able to import my style in dummy app by including `@import 'addon/styles/addon.scss';` in `tests/dummy/app/styles/app.scss` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544976/4096120)

But if I was to include my addon's style in app not using scss, what would be the steps?